# C++ vector, what does this code mean?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
 const int maxnodes = 5000;
 struct Edge 
 {
   int to, rev;
   int f, cap;
 };

 vector<Edge> g[maxnodes];
```

This is quite understandable, but I saw in later lines it used as

```
 Edge &e = g[u][j];
```

here, `'u,j'` are integers. what is `"g[u][j]"`? `'g'` is vector filled with `'Edge'` struct, how can it be act like a array of arrays?

I know `Edge &e` is a reference, and it is receiving a '`Edge`' structure, but I am confused at `'g[u][j]'`.

The source code is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo_cpp/dinic_flow)

Thanks in advance!
:)

Comment: `vector<Edge> g[maxnodes];` is a C-array of vectors.

Comment: For 1) it means that nodes is initialized with value of maxnodes (which must be a constant), and that other two (src and dest) are integer with no initial value...

Comment: Don't ask two unrelated questions in one question. In this case, I've edited  out the first because it's unrelated to the title and you should consult your C++ textbook. It was a beginners question, really.

Comment: Wow, maybe I am tired today, now I seeing it clearly. thank you everyone who answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `int nodes = maxnodes, src, dest;`

Here, `nodes` is an `int` initialized with the value same as that of `maxnodes`. `src` and `dest` are also `int`, but with no initial value.

2) `vector<Edge> g[maxnodes];`

`g` is here an array of `std::vector`.

`Edge &e = g[u][j];`

Q. What is `g[u][j]`?

A. It is the `Edge` stored in `g` at the `u`th row and `j`th column.

Q. `g` is `vector` filled with `Edge` struct, how can it be act like a array of arrays?

A. Because `std::vector` has `operator[]` overloaded for itself in its definition. Refer: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Answer (score 2):

`int nodes = maxnodes, src, dest;`

This means all are integer and nodes is initialized with maxnodes

`vector<Edge> g[maxnodes]` is the array of vector.

Vector is like a dynamic array.
g[x] will be pointing to a vector.
g[x][y] will point to a Edge .

Answer (score 1):

```
int nodes = maxnodes, src, dest;
```

Here `nodes, src, dest` are all integers where `nodes` is initialized with `maxnodes` others are not initialized.

```
vector<Edge> g[maxnodes];
```

As `@milleniumbug` mentioned `g` is a C array of vectors:

`g[u][j]` will give `i` th element of `u` th element of array `g`. As `u` the element of `g` is a vector where you can access its members using `[]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is a C-array of vectors

Example with `maxnodes = 5`.
`G[5]`

```
0 -> std::vector<Edge> 
1 -> std::vector<Edge> 
2 -> std::vector<Edge> 
3 -> std::vector<Edge> 
4 -> std::vector<Edge>
```

If each element of `g` contains 5 elements, it would  look like this

```
G
-
0 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
1 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
3 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
4 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Meaning, `g[u][j]`, for example with `g[2][3]` would correspond to the third element in the vector at the second element of `g`.

`g[2][3]`

```
G
-
0 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
1 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2 -> {0, 1, 2, ***3***, 4}
3 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
4 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int nodes = maxnodes, src, dest;
```

is a declaration that is equivalent to these three declarations

```
int nodes = maxnodes;
int src;
int dest;
```

This

```
vector<Edge> g[maxnodes];
```

is a declaration of an array of objects of type `std::vector<Edge>`. You can use the subscript operator with arrays.

So expression `g[u]` yields the element of the array with index `u` that is a reference to an object of type `std::vector<Edge>`.

Class `std::vector` also overloads the subscript operator. So expression
`g[u][j]` gives the object of type `Edge` with index `j` in the vector of the array with index `u`.

Dcelaration

```
Edge &e = g[u][j];
```

declares a reference to this object of type `Edge`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe others have already explained what each line does well. I'm just pointing out that in the second line,

```
Edge &e = g[u][j];
```

the code places the `Edge` at `g[u][j]` in a reference, presumably, to make the following code easier to both read and write (instead of repeating `g[u][j]` multiple times).